# NPN Transistor not triggering

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, sensor, npn

[image: schematic]

[image]

In the circuit I have a proximity sensor that is triggering a relay by going to a micro-controller.  This is working fine until the micro-controller ignores the sensor (due to a fail safe I have programmed into the controller), upon a soft reset (NOT A REBOOT, sending a signal to the controller to come out of inactive mode), the sensor is still sending 5VDC when it shouldn't be sending anymore then 1VDC.  What is the cause of this? or How can it be fixed?

Note, Everything runs normally if I hold something in front of the proximity sensor for a second or two, then take it away?

Short Recap:
Sensor works fine  -->  controller ignores input due to another input --> controller starts receiving input --> sensor sends out 5VDC even if nothing is in front of it.

Sensor Information:
Proxmity sensor
6VDC input @ 300mA max

Micro-Controller:
Arduino Based Micro-Controller
Input pins - 40mA max

[image: Sensor Wiring Diagram:]

Questions/Answers:

> 1. Are you powering the sensor from 6 V DC?

Yes, the Sensor is being powered by 6 V DC.

Provide a link to the sensor so that we don't have to look it up.

> 2. What is the pot wiper connected to?

I would assume the wiper is connected to the Signal line(Black).  Its not an external pot.

> 3. Why have you added a pot? Is it to reduce the voltage to the micro-controller? If so, what voltage is the micro running on?

The controller is running 5VDC but is a more "rugged" arduino that can take up to 30VDC per I/O pins.

> 4. Provide a link to the sensor so that we don't have to look it up.

- [Amazon link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008FZC8F2).
- [LJ18A3-8-Z/EX datasheet](http://www.ekt2.com/pdf/14_PROXIMITY_INDUCTIVE_18EX.pdf).

Comment: Edit your post, click the Schematic icon in the editing toolbar, draw the circuit diagram.

Comment: How should anyone point out what you did wrong without knowing what you did?

Comment: If I had a wiring diagram of the sensor I'd gladly supply it.  I'll draw up what I have, but it isn't much.

Comment: I have edited my original post.  That is the wiring diagram I could find.  From the black wire I just have it going to a pin on the micro-controller with a internal pull-up resistor.  So fairly simple setup.

Comment: What is connected to the cathode of the diode? What is connected to the base of the transistor? What is that thing with Chinese symbols on it? Edit your post, click the Schematic icon in the editing toolbar, draw a *proper* and *complete* circuit diagram.

Comment: @Dampmaskin I cannot say without dismantling the sensor (ruining it in the process).  I have looked all over for a english version of the schematic and did not find one.  Thus my reasoning for coming here for slightly broad answers.  Most NPN transistor controlled sensors act similar correct?  None the less I drew up a schematic of a similar one I found connected to that model #.  Other then that I don't know what more I can provide.  The model# of the sensor is: lj18a3-8-z/bx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fo1Dj1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Crime scene reconstruction.*

If this schematic represents what you have done then copy it into your question. (You can edit my post, edit the schematic, copy and then cancel out of the edits.) When you do, please clarify the following in your question (and not in the comments):

1. Are you powering the sensor from 6 V DC?
2. What is the pot wiper connected to?
3. Why have you added a pot? Is it to reduce the voltage to the micro-controller? If so, what voltage is the micro running on?
4. Provide a link to the sensor so that we don't have to look it up.

> Sensor Information: Proxmity sensor 6 V DC input @ 300mA max.

The 300 mA is likely the maximum current it can sink - not how much the prox element consumes.

> Micro-Controller: Arduino Based Micro-Controller Input pins - 40mA max.

That's the maximum output current from an Arduino pin. You're using it as an input so this is irrelevant.

---

Edit after additional info provided.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD10B4.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. More likely setup.*

The [switch datasheet](http://www.ekt2.com/pdf/14_PROXIMITY_INDUCTIVE_18EX.pdf) was easily found in a web search. There is no mention of a potentiometer on the output but the spec does say "Set distance: 0 - 7 mm" so I assume there is a sensitivity adjustment on the back. This does not attenuate the output as you drew it. It adjusts the switching point. The output still switches fully on or fully off.

Try wiring it up as shown in Figure 2 and report back.

Comment: I've added the answers to your questions in the OP.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I did just find another wiring diagram.  I uploaded it to the OP.  It shows a better and more accurate explanation.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: I just tested Figure 2 with some slight modifications.  I have the sensor connected to a power supply that supplies both the controller and the sensor.  So I left the ground going back to the power supply vs. going to the controller.  I don't know if the controller can take the 6V without damaging it.  I did add a resistor in series to the power of the micro but I apperently don't have any 1K resistors so I used a 10k,  With all of this in perspective I got the same results as before.  The sensor reads LOW but sends an output of 5V.

Comment: @Matt You have a power supply supplying power to controller and sensor without a ground to controller?  Use an optocoupler.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I have power coming from the wall wart(power supply), positive going out to my sensor box, and power going to the controller, both with grounds leading back to the wall warts, ground connection.  So I believe they technically share the same ground.  I will include my complete wiring diagram.   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0lRN3VXhPvyMHpVSjh0T2UweDQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You can't regulate the voltage to a dynamic load such as a micro-controller by using a resistor. You need a regulator if there isn't one in the Arduino.

Comment: What does "*The sensor reads LOW but sends an output of 5V*" mean? Where are the prox switches on your schematic?

Comment: I just got it figured out.  It was a programming issue, or at least I solved it by programming it a different way.  I'm not sure what you mean by regulated voltage with a resistor.  The voltage is regulated by a linear voltage regulator.  The resistors in my schematic are either pull-down resistors or a resistor needed for the LCD display.   The prox switches are the "IR" sensors at the bottom.  3 pins.  Its not the best schematic and I still have alot of clean up to do on it.

Comment: I was looking at R1 at the top of the schematic connected to VIN but now that I look again I can't see how the Arduino is powered. Glad you got sorted. Have a look around for a better schematic editor! Bye.

Comment: Yes, I will do.  Thank you for your time!  It was appreciated.

Comment: @Matt: Don't forget to accept the answer if it is correct. Thanks.